# Global Access Variable Rights, That Are Set In My CakePHP AppController

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having problems with trying to set global variables with my CakePHP 2.2.2 app. I have defined the following inside my AppController :

```
 App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

 class AppController extends Controller {

  function beforeFilter() {

   $MenuTest = "MENU TEST";
   $this->set('Menu', $MenuTest);

  } //End of beforeFilter()
}
```

This is meant to set $MenuTest as a global variable right? So I should be able to access $MenuTest on any controller or view I want? An less I am missing something?

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class PagesController extends AppController {

public $name = 'Pages';
public $uses = array();

 public function display() {
    debug( $Menu);
    die();
    $this->render('home');
 }//End of function display()

 function test () {
    echo $Menu;
    echo 'This is testing a new link';
    die();
 }//End of function test()
}
```

When I load my page, all that debug gives me is a 'null'. Again the same when I use the test function?

Please help? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks, Glenn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Controller::set()` sets a view var, not a class var. If you want a class var inherited by all sub-classes you would do `$this->Menu = 'Some value';` and access with `$this->Menu`.

Comment: Actually in his examples he's not even checking a class var/property but rather a local var inside each function which obviously isn't going to work.